# How do I use grep to parse a portion of bash command output into a variable?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

```
$ file myImage.png
```

Produces this result:

```
myImage.png: PNG image data, 42 x 64, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```

I want to parse the width and the height into variables, something like this:

```
MY_WIDTH  = file myImage.png | grep ???x
MY_HEIGHT = file myImage.png | grep x???
```

Comment: Try awk.  You can use it to parse out fields (i.e. columns) of output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use subgroup capturing with a regular expression match:

```
regex='([0-9]+) x ([0-9]+)'
[[ $(file myImage.png) =~ $regex ]] && {
    MY_WIDTH=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    MY_HEIGHT=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Bonus +1 for putting the regex in a variable. Bash changed the way it does regexes [between 3.1 and 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes), so storing them in a variable gives maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

If you are indeed interested in the resolution of an image, there are better utilities than [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) in the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package. Specifically the [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) tool:

```
MY_WIDTH=$(identify -format "%w" myImage.png)
MY_HEIGHT=$(identify -format "%h" myImage.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you will need a regular expression that detects the ' x ' pattern with the numbers on either side.

[This thread may help you start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496437/sed-regex-to-find-monitor-resolution) as it says:

```
xrandr|grep -Po '\d+(?=\s*x.*\*.*)'
```

instead you could do

```
RES = file myImage.png ||grep -Po '\d+(?=\s*x.*\*.*)'
```

then modify accordingly to seperate the two into your variables

Comment: There are several syntax errors, and you ignore the difficult part of parsing two substrings out of the result of the `grep`.